# Restaurant day by day number of meals served

Tags: dataframe, csv

I'm looking for a dataframe which gives a day by day number of meals served for a restaurant (any restaurant would work).

Does anyone know if this exists ?

Thanks

Comment: If any restaurant would work, you actually don't know the capacity or opening hours of said restaurant. And could you not then just as well use random data from [Mockaroo](https://mockaroo.com/) or similar ? Or create your own list programmatically based on set variations ?

Comment: @MyICQ maybe my question was wrongly asked. My goal is to build a model to predict the number of people that will come to a given restaurant each day. I'm just looking for a day by day data frame of the number of people that came to a certain restaurant to test and improve my model. Thus, I don't think using random data is a good idea, as I would need real information to test it. So I'm just looking for a bunch of real data of a restaurant.